# jQuery Mobile swipe down and swipe up for Android mobile site

Tags: android, iphone, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

Does anyone knows how to set right code for swipe down and up on mobile devices with jquery?

Thanks

Comment: No code? What have you tried? How are you trying to do this?

Comment: http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.de/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately swipeup and swipedown don't exist in jQuery mobile and they are not planed for version 1.3. There is an 3rd party plugin here: http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html. Use them like you would use normal events: swipedown and swipeup.

You can also use this plugin if you need this implementation: http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library. It also works on Android devices. This is a worst case scenario solution because unlike official event there ones don't work on desktop browsers.

```
$("#wrapper").touchwipe({
     wipeLeft: function() { 
         $("#carousel").trigger("next", 1);
     },
     wipeRight: function() { 
         $("#carousel").trigger("next", 1);        
     },
     min_move_x: 20,
     min_move_y: 20,
     preventDefaultEvents: true
});
```

**EDIT :**

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/97h45/ Test it only on Android and iOs devices. I have tested it on iOS 6 and Android 4.1.1

Comment: I tried with first link and that code only works in desktop browsers not on mobile android and iphone.. Second link.

Comment: What about second link? I have update my answer with a second solution example.

Comment: sorry, yes second link.. I'm trying to implement that and maybe it is probably a good solution..